# Is it possible to put Google Chrome into a "extension free" mode?

Tags: debugging, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Is there a way to temporary deactivate all (or selected) Google Chrome extensions? This would be handy when I debug pages, since some extensions (eg. AdBlock, Clickable Links etc) modify the content of web pages.

Also sometimes I want to monitor how a page loads via the Chrome developer tool's timeline. But since extension-activity also is recorded it can get a bit messy.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Open an Incognito window.]

https://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=95464

Answer (score -1):

<s>Sorry guys. I should have done some better research before posting here. I searched in chrome web store and found this extension, which seems to do the thing. Sorry for bothering you.</s>

This solution was discarded since a better suggestion was given (see accepted answer).

Comment: Hi, could you post the link or at least the name of the extension pls? I'm also troubled by this problem

Comment: I don't remember which extension it was anymore, but it might be this one: http://goo.gl/yrwLaF. I do however recommend using incognito mode; I found it to be easier to use (just make sure to uncheck "Allow in incognito" for all extensions in chrome://extensions/ ).